# Would a ring magnet around a copper tube be slowed?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

if a ring-shaped magnet was dropped with a copper pole through the center would it be slowed the same as a cylindrical magnet in a copper tube? if so would it be slowed more or less?

Comment: Depends on the changing magnetic flux, but I would say it would fall faster.

Comment: "Ring-shaped" does not tell us how many pole pairs the magnet has, or how the poles are oriented.

Comment: @SolomonSlow would that change the answer? and how so?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I know that there are [at least two different ways](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/magdir.asp) of making a "ring magnet." Most have only two poles, but then there are crazy outliers like [this guy](https://www.arborsci.com/products/multipole-neodymium-super-ring-magnet).

Comment: @SolomonSlow i was thinking of axially aligned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, yes.

Eddy currents are induced in conductors exposed to changing magnetic fields. Those currents specifically counter the change in magnetic flux the conductor is experiencing. That's Lentz's law. Or, more formally it's faraday's law. Part of Maxwell's equations describing how classical electromagnetism works on a fundamental level.

Translation:

Dropping a cylinder magnet in a metal tube? Slowed.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H31K9qcmeMU

Dropping a ring magnet around a metal tube? Still slowed.
Sliding a ring magnet along a metal sheet? Slowed
Sliding a regular magnet along a metal sheet? Slowed
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KsnKHsD3Ak

Swinging a conducting pendulum through poles of a horseshoe-type magnet? Slowed
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHwvbywdpuQ

Dropping a magnet directly onto a conductor? Slowed
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ajjoi2CfI20

Dropping a square magnet through a thick metal tube? Slowed
Rolling a thick metal tube towards a magnet? Slowed
Ahh, but plot twist. Leaving a magnet stationary inside a tube and then lifting it up? Sped up (since resisting the "move the magnet away from the tube" change in flux would require the magnet to move along with the tube).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q7leJTZ6E48

Rule of thumb: If you're trying to speed up the magnet or tube, eddy currents will slow them down. If you're trying to slow down the magnet or tube, eddy currents will speed them up.